# Simple Python: about structure of code

Tags: python, if-statement, structure

```
print ("This program reads an unsigned binary number of arbitrary length 
\nand tries to compute the decimal equivalent. The program reports an error 
\nif the input number contains characters other than 0 and 1.")
dec = 0
bin = 0
factor = 1

print ("Enter the binary number: ")
bin = int(input())

while(bin > 0):

    if((bin % 10) == True):
        dec += factor
        bin //= 10
        factor = factor * 2


    else:
        print("unrecognized bit:")


print ("I think your binary number in decimal form is: " ,dec)
```

This is my code for a program that is supposed to convert a binary number from the user into a decimal number. It works fine, but I'm trying to add an "else" statement that will print "unrecognized bit" if the user enters a number other than 0 or 1. It kinds works, however the program prints "Unrecognized bit" even if the user has only entered 0 and 1's. This shouldn't happen. Also, see picture related. I've entered 12343 to test the program, and it says Unrecognized bit which is good but it also takes the "1" in that number and converts it to 16 which shouldn't happen, it should just say unrecognized bit. I think these two problems are simple to fix but I'm just not sure. Thank you!

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM5u6.png)

Comment: The indentation of the code in your question is messed-up—please [edit] your question and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The conditional is only satisfied if your binary input has a remainder of 1, since `0 == False` evaluates to `True`. That is to say, if your number ends with a zero (or in fact, *contains* a zero), `(bin%10) == True` will evaluate to `False` (side point: there's actually no need to add the `== True` on the right).
2. You're adding `factor` to `dec` regardless of whether the digit you're looking at is a `1` or `0`; you shouldn't be adding if you encounter a zero.

So your code should look like this:

```
while(bin > 0):
    remainder = (bin % 10)
    if remainder in (0,1):
        dec += factor * remainder
        bin //= 10
        factor = factor * 2

    else:
        print("unrecognized bit:")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks man you fixed it! One more problem though... when I enter something like 12345 that would trigger the "Unrecognized bit" statement, "Unrecognized bit" prints out about a bazillion times when I run the program for some reason.  Do you know why this could be? Should I add a break in there somewhere?

Comment: Yes, add a break. The loop keeps going because you're not changing the value of `bin` if your conditional is false.

Comment: Sorry for so many questions, but I added the break statement after the if statement and its now saying that the else statement is invalid syntax...

Comment: The `break` goes after the `print` in the `else` clause. I'll just edit my answer.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I am a beginner so this really helped me learn some :)

Answer (score 0):

Its a question of indentation. Your last line will print no matter what the if else statements say. You also want to exit the while loop when you reach an unrecognized symbol. Right now it prints the else statement but keeps looping.

This is a fix where I added a break condition to exit the else, then added a boolean to see if we can output the last print statement:

```
print ("This program reads an unsigned binary number of arbitrary length tries to compute the decimal equivalent. The program reports an error if the input number contains characters other than 0 and 1.")
dec = 0
bin = 0
factor = 1
success = 1

print ("Enter the binary number: ")
bin = int(input())

while(bin > 0):

  if((bin % 10) == True):
      dec += factor
      bin //= 10
      factor = factor * 2


  else:
      print("unrecognized bit:")
      success = 0
      break

if(success):
  print ("I think your binary number in decimal form is: " ,dec)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to test your input to be sure it is legal. You can do this using regular expressions. Replace `bin = int(input())` with:

```
import re    
inp = input()
if re.match('.*[^01]+.*', inp) is not None:
    print("illegal character in input, must be ones and/or zeros")
    exit()

bin = int(inp)
```

This will print the illegal character message if the input contains anything but ones or zeros.